# bit width of concatenated arrays in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I have multiple functions that generate concatenated array of 1 bit variables/defines/enums. Everytime a concatenation happens i want to make sure the final size is 32 bits wide. And flag an error if it is less than or greater than 32 bits. 
i have tried $bits, $size, but they seem to be wanting a variable and provide the variable width not the width of concatenation. which defeats the purpose.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

here is what i was thinking :-
For example.

```
logic [31:0] var_out;


function f1(bunch of inputs generated by macros(variable no. of input) a,b,c)
size({a,b,c}); 
var_out = {a,b,c};
endfunction

function f2(bunch of inputs generated by macros(variable no. of input) e,f,g,h,i) 
size({e,f,g,h,i});
var_out = {e,f,g,h,i};
endfunction

function size (in) **// what should be in this function ?**
if(length(in)!=32) - $error("msg"); *// this is what i want to achieve*
```

Comment: If these functions are generated by macros anyways, why don't you just put `if ($bits({a,b,c}) != 32) $error()` into the function?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in SystemVerilog that takes a number of arguments lets you define it to take a variable number of arguments. (you can have default arguments, but there is no way of knowing from inside the function if the default was used)

Why not

```
function f1(bunch of inputs generated by macros(variable no. of input) a,b,c)
  size_check($bits({a,b,c})); 
  var_out = {a,b,c};
endfunction
function void size (int in) **// what should be in this function ?**
if(in !=32) - $error("msg"); *// this is what i want to achieve*
endfunction
```